# Install error with "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

Tags: python, github, installation

I want to install [pygrowup2 library](https://github.com/jbaldivieso/pygrowup2) from github.
When I download the file and run the setup.py file in VSC:

"
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

".

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that part of the problem is that the package in GitHub  is named misleadingly–it really should be installed as `pygrowup`.

A more successful way to install this version of the package is to use pip's ability to install directly from version control. Try using `pip install git+https://github.com/jbaldivieso/pygrowup2.git#egg=pygrowup`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).